# 64 bit processor running at 32 bit on mac

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32-bit, processor

according to [apple's mac processor list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3696?viewlocale=it_IT&locale=it_IT) a i5 should be a 64 bit processor. According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_900148&feature=iv&src_vid=srbdMHivkpo&v=akjVaF09mSY) if i type `uname -m` in terminal i should get x86_64. but in my case it says i386 instead. why is that? i developed also an app, that is a 64 bit only app. that app is NOT running on this mac. it crashes at start. but if i compile in x86_64 mode instead of 64 bit only then it works. does somebody have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "64 bit only"? x86_64 is 64 bit only.

Comment: x86_64 **is** 64-bit.

Comment: See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3773 and http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770

Comment: sorry i dont have the mac in front of me so maybe i recall it wrong. when compiling i have 3 options: one for 64 bit only, one for 32 and 64 bit, and one for 32 bit only. what i meant is the option to compile for 32 bit and 64 bit. the one that forces me to diable ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is not supported under 32-bit runtimes.  Therefore if you are using ARC you will need to produce 64-bit binaries only.

From [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Comment: thanks but my question is basically: if the processor is an i5, why doesn't it run my 64 bit-Only app, but does successfully run a 32/64 bit app?

Comment: If OSX has been booted into 32-bit mode then it will use the 32-bit binary in favour of the 64-bit binary.  If you boot into 64-bit mode it will use the 64-bit instead.

Comment: is there a disadvantage in permanently boot into 64 bit mode? thanks for your help!

Comment: @Justme No, not at all, but it depends on what OSX version you are running maybe.

Comment: on this specific mac 10.6.8

Comment: @Justme Follow the discussion on the following page to enable 64-bit kernel boot by default: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3521151?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @trojanfoe: The kernel mode has nothing to do with the mode userland programs run in. On a 64-bit CPU, 32/64 bit apps will launch in 64-bit mode by default (unless it's overridden somehow) no matter what the kernel mode is.

Answer (score 1):

The video is wrong: `uname -m` tells you what mode the kernel is running in, which has very little to do with userland programs such as yours. If you want to to find out for sure if the CPU is 64-bit capable, use `sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable` -- since you have an i5, it should print `hw.cpu64bit_capable: 1` meaning "yes" (0 would mean "no"). Also, run the Activity Monitor utility, and note the modes various processes are running in -- my guess is that a lot will be in "Intel (64 bit)", since in 10.6 most of the programs supplied with OS X came in 32/64-bit dual architecture, and will prefer 64-bit.

Now, about your app: It should run in 64-bit mode whether you compile it 64-bit only or 63/64, so I doubt that's the problem. To be sure, compile it 32/64, run it, then use Activity Monitor to see what mode it's actually running in.

I can't tell for sure, but my guess would be that your app has a problem with ARC. At least as I understand it, that's only enabled if you compile 64-bit only (and disabled if you compile 32/64).

Comment: thank you very much! i tried to install xcode 4.2 on the older mac and when i loaded the project it gave an error for CFNetwork.framework. (not having this error on xcode 4.6) thanks for your tipps anyway! what should i pay attention NOT to do with ARC enabled? thanks!

Comment: @Justme: Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with ARC (and it could be some other difference between the compilation modes that I don't know about). I'd suggest falling back on basic debugging: check the crash logs, run in debugger, look for leaks, etc.